# Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I try to add the 'firebase_storage' package to project .. but I receive this error although I added the reference to pubsec.yaml file .. I tried pub get and flutter packages get and restarted the IDE and still facing the same problem:

> Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart'.
> Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.

```
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
```

I receive this error when I run flutter pub get

> Because taala depends on permission_handler >=1.0.1 <6.0.0 which doesn't support null safety, version solving
> failed.
>
> The lower bound of "sdk: '>=2.0.0-dev.58.0 <3.0.0'" must be 2.12.0
> or higher to enable null safety.
> For details, see https://dart.dev/null-safety

here is pubspec.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
 flutter:
 sdk: flutter
 better_textfield:  


 # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your 
 application.
 # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
 cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
 firebase_core: ^2.8.0
 firebase_auth: ^4.3.0
 cloud_firestore: ^4.2.0
 image_picker: ^0.8.7+5
 permission_handler: ^5.0.1+1
 firebase_storage: ^11.2.2
 get:
```

it is now doesn`t work with package I add

Comment: What flutter version and sdk are you using? Which firebase_storage version are you using? After running "flutter pub get" did it say code 0? Did you try running flutter clean?

Comment: Show your `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: @Texv Dart SDK version is 3.0.2... Flutter version 3.10.2....firebase_storage 11.2.2....it gives me exit code 1

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem is to upgrade flutter versions:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```